# Associate a control with a resource key in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there any way to associate a control such as a `nameLabel` with a local resource key from code behind.

I usually do this from *html* using the `meta:resourcekey` property like the following:

```
<asp:Label ID="nameLabel" runat="server" 
    meta:resourcekey="nameLabel" />
```

Thanx :)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
nameLabel.Text = Resources.Resource1.nameLabel;
```

Here:

Resource1 is the name of resource file (Resource1.resx) which is placed in App_GlobalResources folder

Check this for details:

[How to: Retrieve Resource Values Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227982%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

[ASP.NET Localization](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38907/ASP-NET-Localization-Quick-Reference)

Comment: I asked about associating a control with a resource key. I know how to retrieve resource values :/

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
btn.Text = GetLocalResourceObject("Resource Key").ToString();
```

You will automatically get the value from desire resource key in App_Localresources.